# Microsoft Blend 3 - Add Silverlight SDK Themes

Tags: wpf, silverlight, expression-blend

I'm working on my first WPF project and would like to use one of the themes that I see in the Silverlight Tool Kit.

All the help I've found is for Expression 2 and they show a different version of the Asset Tab.  Can someone advise me how to do this.  It looks like it should be simple, but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Import the xaml theme file into your Blend project (ex: ShinyBlue.xaml).  Click on the Resources tab and find the xaml file you just imported (ShinyBlue.xaml).  If you expand it you should find all of the styles and templates.  By default the ResourceDictionary will be added to the app.xaml file and all of your controls should be restyled to the theme you just added.  Let me know if this helps.